# Synchronize WPF animation issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I cannot to synchronize WPF animation of the position and size at the same time.

Please have a look at my code and let me know if something is wrong there.

Thank you!

```
 void AnimatePlugin(double fromTop, double toTop, double fromLeft, double toLeft,
            double fromH, double toH, double fromW, double toW, UIElement control)
        {
            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

            #region Top

            DoubleAnimation daTop = new DoubleAnimation();
            daTop.From = fromTop;
            daTop.To = toTop;
            daTop.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            sb.Children.Add(daTop);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daTop, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(daTop, control);
            #endregion

            #region Left

            DoubleAnimation daLeft = new DoubleAnimation();
            daLeft.From = fromLeft;
            daLeft.To = toLeft;
            daLeft.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            sb.Children.Add(daLeft);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daLeft, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(daLeft, control);
            #endregion

            #region Heigh

            DoubleAnimation daH = new DoubleAnimation();
            daH.From = fromH;
            daH.To = toH;
            daH.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            sb.Children.Add(daH);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daH, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Height)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(daH, control);
            #endregion

            #region Width

            DoubleAnimation daW = new DoubleAnimation();
            daW.From = fromW;
            daW.To = toW;
            daW.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            sb.Children.Add(daW);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(daW, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Width)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(daW, control);
            #endregion

            sb.Completed += (w, r) => { control.UpdateLayout(); };
            sb.Begin();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `Canvas.Left` and and `Canvas.Top` are attached properties....(and you are specifying them correctly with brackets).

However, "Width" and "Height" are not attached properties they are base properties of FrameworkElement......just use `PropertyPath("Width")` and `PropertyPath("Height")`

Instead of using a string to specify the path to the property, you can use the PropertyPath that takes a DependencyProperty type.....so use `PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty)`, `PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty)`, `PropertyPath(Canvas.WidthProperty)`, `PropertyPath(Canvas.HeightProperty)`.

This way you don't need to worry yourself with using the correct syntax for the `PropertyPath` string, which is different depending on if the property is attached or not.

Comment: Well I did changes you have suggested and no success.

Comment: Instead of a string, use the PropertyPath that takes explicity types so use PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty), PropertyPath(Canvas.LeftProperty), PropertyPath(Canvas.WidthProperty), PropertyPath(Canvas.HeightProperty)